# Rotating Vectors in space

Tags: vector, rotation

I have two sets of vectors,

```
(* SET_1:  *)

A0 = {-23.645, 8.761, 19.186};
A1 = {8.909, 11.977, -26.572};
A2 = { 6.098, 8.537, 31.834};
A3 = {9.866, -32.131, -24.569};

(* SET_2:  *)

B0 = {-13.9469, 28.7731, -3.21699};
B1 = {-13.8077, -27.3636, 0.329735};
B2 = {2.94231, 23.5992, 23.8511};
B3 = {24.8123, -25.0087, -20.9639};
```

These two sets are such that A0 = B0, A1=B1, A2=B2, and A3=B3 (Let's say within experimental error) but only rotated in 3d space.
Now is there any way to know the rotation axis and angle of this transformation so that I can use this information for future use.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the question: Are you looking for the rotationmatrix `R` which maps ` A[i]->B[i]: B[i]=R.A[i]`?

Comment: @Ulrich..Yes I am looking for single rotation matrix which can transform Set A[i]->B[i]

Comment: By the way, the map you are looking for seems to be a reflection, not a rotation.

Comment: It seems like that when we only use TransformationClass -> "Rigid". But if you add Method -> "FindFit", then it looks like in a rotating frame.

Comment: No it's another point: The determinant of the transformation matrix equals `-1` which indicates that the transformation is no rotation!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want a single transformation function for all points, rather than one for each point independently as kglr's answer currently shows.

```
set1 = {A0, A1, A2, A3};
set2 = {B0, B1, B2, B3};

tF2 = FindGeometricTransform[
        set1, set2
         , TransformationClass -> "Rigid"
         , Method -> "FindFit"
      ][[2]];

Graphics3D[{
   {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[set1]},
   {Opacity[.15, Blue], Sphere[tF2@set2, 2]}
}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks...you got my point!!

Comment: Just one remark: FindGeometricTransformation is a nonlinear map. You have to use the option `TransformationClass -> "Rigid"` to get correct results

Comment: Hi..I was working with this transformation, I guess one should use TransformationClass -> "Similarity"...any comment?

Comment: TransformationClass -> "Similarity" includes scaling beside translation and rotation!

Comment: @Ulrich Thank you, I will amend this answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a map  `R.A[i]~B[i] ,i,0,1,2,3` :
First you have to define the rotationmatrix R

```
 ϕ = {{0, -φ3, φ2}, {φ3,0,-φ1}, {-φ2, φ1, 0}};
 φ = Simplify[Sqrt[Tr[-ϕ.ϕ/2]]]
 R = IdentityMatrix[3] + Sin[φ]/φ ϕ + (1 - Cos[φ])/φ^2 ϕ.ϕ ;
```

which depends on `φ1, φ2, φ3`

Now you can calculate the optimal rotation parameters `φ1, φ2, φ3`

```
 J = Total@MapThread[(R.#1 - #2 ).(R.#1 - #2 ) &, {{A0, A1, A2, A3},{B0, B1, B2, B3}}]
 sol=NMinimize[J, {φ1, φ2, φ3}]
 (* {2061.5, {φ1 -> -1.01538, φ2 ->1.45343, φ3 -> 1.3975}} *)
```

The optimal rotationmatrix is

```
Ropt=R /.sol[[2]]     
(*{{-0.303462, -0.951876, 0.0429177}, 
{0.00554758, 0.043276,0.999048}, 
{-0.952827, 0.303411, -0.007852}} *)

Ropt.Transpose[Ropt] (*test:  should be identitymatrix[3] *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [FindGeometricTransform](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindGeometricTransform.html):

```
tFs = MapThread[FindGeometricTransform[{#}, {#2}][[2]] &,
  {{A0, A1, A2, A3}, {B0, B1, B2, B3}}]; 

Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{A0, A1, A2, A3}], Opacity[.15, Blue],
  MapThread[Sphere[#@#2, 2] &, {tFs, {B0, B1, B2, B3}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I interpret this differently; CW below.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, good point. That possibility didn't occur to me.

Comment: Thank you very much guys